# Apps restarts when I pressed home button or switch to other App

Tags: android, android-studio

Device Name: Mi A2 Lite

Android: 10

RAM available: 700 to 1 GB

When I open an App, and pressed home button and app is in background now I want to again open same App, but that App again restarted.

Comment: Need much more information. How many activities you have? maybe a code sample from your launcher activity?

Comment: Not only my app, same issue with all apps, even I open youtube App play video and switched to other app, and again back to youtube App, App restarts again, paused video disappeared

Comment: Since you've mentioned that it's an issue with all of your device's apps, your question should instead be asked on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com) as it's not programming-related.

Comment: @JasolSinghSodha any chance you have the "dont keep activities" developer option on in your phone? that option kills all the activities as soon as they go in the background.

Comment: @CrazySports101 "don't keep activities" option is off in developer option

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me a device problem. I have some friends who own Mi A2 Lite, and they also face this problem. The OS keeps killing the apps as soon as they move to the background.
And if I am right, this problem would have started after the android 10 update. To me, it seems a ram management problem, and to free up ram, your device is killing off applications in the background.

There are some workarounds, but I suppose none of them are permanent. So unless Xiaomi fixes this, you are stuck with this issue as of now.

If you want to try some workarounds, you may see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xiaomi/comments/gt07s8/mi_a2_lite_switching_between_apps_causes_app_to/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share)

Comment: yes after android 10 update, and also my colleague have Nokia phone with android 10 and same issue with him. I restarted device and off background data usage of Apps like facebook, linkedIn, twitter, whatsapp and more, then I saw problem fixed, and now no one app is restarting for now.

Comment: @JasolSinghSodha Yes restart solves the problem but I think that's temporary. After some time it reverts back to killing apps in the background